# How to publish My Plugin on wordpress.org

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i Want to Publish the plugin that i wrote for Wordpress CMS on the 
www.Wordpress.org

Now what should i do to publish my own plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good article in the Codex which outlines the plugin submission process:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_Submission_and_Promotion